How can I decode base64 and quoted-printable emails and encode as 7/8bit emails in Python?
I want to decode base64 and quoted-printable MIME emails in Python, such that I either get an email.message.Message (or email.message.EmailMessage) or string representing the entire email as though it were encoded with 7/8bit encoding.
I've tried the following:
import email.message

def decode_email(message: email.message.Message) -> email.message.Message:
    """Turn a quoted-printable or base64 encoded email into a 7or8bit encoded
    email

    :param message: email.message.Message to be decoded
    :return: decoded email.message.Message"""
    payload = []

    for part in message.walk():
        if not part.is_multipart():
            payload.append(part.get_payload(decode=True))

    message["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "7bit"
    message.set_payload(payload)

    return message

However there seem to be issues with message, e.g. when I try to cast it to a string:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/revsuine/testing.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(decode_email(msg).as_string())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/message.py", line 188, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/generator.py", line 117, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/generator.py", line 182, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/generator.py", line 219, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/generator.py", line 286, in _handle_multipart
    g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False, linesep=self._NL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/email/generator.py", line 108, in flatten
    old_msg_policy = msg.policy
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'policy'

I assume I've misunderstood how to use set_payload(), but the Python documentation doesn't seem to say what the payload you're supposed to pass to this method actually is. Thanks for any help in advance
